# Display text on bootstrap progress bar if bar is empty

Tags: php, html, text, progress-bar

So I have a bootstrap progress bar where text is displayed within the bar - I've noticed that the text only shows if the bar has SOME amount of fill, but if the bar is empty, the text isn't shown?

How can I edit this HTML to show the text inside the bar if the bar is empty as well as full or anywhere in between?

```
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%;">
    This is my text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-label)

> To ensure that the label text remains legible even for low percentages, consider adding a min-width to the progress bar.

[image]

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em;">
    0%
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width: 2%;">
    2%
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, perhaps something like this would work:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
     style="min-width: 20%"> <!-- or use ems/pixels -->
    This is my text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this way make no sense, if there's 0% in the bar, the bar must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

According to [@TomSawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085848/tomsawyer) comment, when there is 0% in the bar, the bar must be empty and there is no bar to show the text. But we can add another div element to show text on the background and align the text center, like this code:

```
<div class="progress position-relative">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria- valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%; color: black;">
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex position-absolute w-100">
        Zero percent
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress position-relative">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria- valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%; color: black;">
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex position-absolute w-100">
        Ten percent
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine with Bootstrap v5.